# Can a TF graph feed into another without leaving the GPU in one session?

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose I have two TF graphs `G_1`, `G_2` and I want to take the output of `G_1` and feed it into `G_2`. My assumption is that to do this we enter the GPU on feed of `G_1` and then taking the output of `G_1` and feeding it into `G_2` goes out to the CPU.

Is there any way to feed both graphs on the GPU?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In general you do not have to specify CPUs or GPUs explicitly. TensorFlow uses your first GPU, if you have one, for as many operations as possible.

The output of `G_1` will go into `G-2` which will also be executed on the GPU.

resource: [Tensorflow Basic Usage](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/get_started/basic_usage.html#launching-the-graph-in-a-session)

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers my question. When I feed into `G_1` and get the output and then feed that into `G_2` doesn't that go from GPU to CPU to GPU? If so, how do I link the output of `G_1` and `G_2`.

Comment: You would take the output from `G_1` and feed it into the session running `G_2`. The same way you were putting input into `G_1`.

Comment: Does that not leave the GPU?

Comment: It would exit the GPU after the first session has completed (`G-1` has be computed) and then would return enter the GPU when computer `G_2`

Comment: Okay so now that we are on the same page. Is it possible to link the graphs in such away that only one session runs and the input from `G_1` is fed to `G_2` without exiting the GPU? Or would I have to make a third graph which is a copy of the first two using `reuse=True`? This is the essence of my question.

Comment: simply combine `G_1` and `G_2` into a single graph. This would execute the two graphs without exiting the GPU. You could use `Fetches` to retrieve any necessary data from the point where  the current `G_1` ends and `G_2` begins